# Speed up Port Scan C#

Tags: c#, sockets, web, port-scanning

I am trying to create port scanner in C#, so far I have this:

```
private void ip()
{
    int start = 70;
    int end = 80;
    string ipString;
    if (this.comboBox1.Text == "Domain") {
         ipString= Dns.GetHostEntry(txtHost.Text).AddressList[0].ToString();
    }
    else {
        ipString = txtHost.Text;
    }
    TcpClient asd = new TcpClient();
    // MessageBox.Show(ipString);     
    IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(ipString);
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            asd.SendTimeout = 3000;
            asd.ReceiveTimeout = 3000;
            asd.Connect(address, i);

            if (asd.Connected)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Port " + i + " is open");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Port " + i + " is closed");
        }
    }
}
```

However for closed ports, it's kinda slow, around 20 seconds, what should I do to make the process faster?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: "it's kinda slow". You should measure which bit is slow so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331902/c-sharp-tcp-port-scanner-resources

Comment: You should consider the async networking APIs. There are many to choose from, but if you value your sanity, consider .net4.5 and the async/await apis. Also worth considering that none of the .net DNS apis are any good. Perhaps a 3rd party option might be considered. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480742/dns-begingethost-methods-blocking

Comment: Slow, around 20 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You should use threading.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx

Fire up separate thread for every port you want to check and let the callbacks inform you which of them is open and which is not.

Comment: How can I call thread with multiple parameters ? 

private void ip(strin ip, int start, int end)
{
}

?

Comment: How can you suggest this when you don't even know which part is "kinda slow"? Adding extra threads is rarely a good answer to speeding up networking code.

Comment: Threading is going to be needed in any case since his code would block the main UI thread no matter what he did. Networking code needs threading.

Comment: @IgorPerić Not necessarily, there are quite capable async methods in TcpClient too.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your delegate and async function declared like this (two parameters in example)

```
public delegate void UpdateUIThreadDelegate(int par1, int par2);
void UpdateUIThread(int par1, int par2)
{
       ...
}
```

And you should call you async function like this:

```
this.Invoke(new UpdateUIThreadDelegate(UpdateUIThread), new object[] { par1, par2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the connection after you are done testing it.

try `asd.Close();` at the end of your `catch` statement.

It sped up the process for me significantly.